# Parsing web page with selenium return InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm having trouble creating a "click" to switch to next page in the website: "[https://www.remax.pt/comprar?searchQueryState={%22regionName%22:%22%22,%22businessType%22 : 1,% 22listingClass% 22: 1,% 22page% 22: 1,% 22sort% 22: {% 22fieldToSort% 22:% 22ContractDate% 22,% 22order% 22: 1},% 22mapIsOpen% 22: false,% 22listingTypes % 22: [],% 22prn% 22:% 22% 22}](https://Hello%20%20I%27m%20having%20trouble%20creating%20a) "

Until now I have this python code:

```
import requests

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json

# Grab content from URL
url = "https://www.remax.pt/comprar?searchQueryState={%22regionName%22:%22%22,%22businessType%22:1,%22listingClass%22:1,%22page%22:1,%22sort%22:{%22fieldToSort%22:%22ContractDate%22,%22order%22:1},%22mapIsOpen%22:false,%22listingTypes%22:[],%22prn%22:%22%22}"
```

But now, here comes the problem:

```
option = Options()
option.headless = True
chromedriver = "/Users/Jô Silva/Documents/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # in seconds


reallyLongXpathLocator = (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[7]/a')

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid" id="root"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@col-md-12 no-padding"]//div//div[@class="listing-search-component fullscreen"]//div[@class="mobile map-closed"]//div[2]//div[@class="pagination-component"]//ul[@class="pagination"]//li[@class="arrow page-item"]//a[@class="page-link" role="button" href="#"]').click()

driver.find_element(reallyLongXpathLocator).click()

driver.quit()
```

Now i get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

Why is that? And what can I do to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply wait for the element and click the next a tag. Currently works in non headless. It has some bot detection when you get into headless.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.remax.pt/comprar?searchQueryState={%22regionName%22:%22%22,%22businessType%22:1,%22listingClass%22:1,%22page%22:1,%22sort%22:{%22fieldToSort%22:%22ContractDate%22,%22order%22:1},%22mapIsOpen%22:false,%22listingTypes%22:[],%22prn%22:%22%22}")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.='Aceitar']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='page-link'][.//span[.='Next']]"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```